# Lecture notes for measure theoretic probability theory

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory

I'm looking for good lecture notes (or concise books) that develop probability theory from a measure theoretic point of view. In particular, I'm looking for a text where the measure theoretic part is developed only as far as needed for probability theory. (I'm not really interested in measure theory on its own.)

Comment: Does any one know anything about the book by Krishna Athreya, Measure Theory and Probability Theory?  I ask because I know it is available on Springer Link as a PDF, which is free if your university has a subscription.  So, it's an actual textbook, but with the same cost as lecture notes.

Comment: I wonder how is it possible to distinguish a part of measure theory which is not needed for probability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My favorite introduction to measure theoretic probability is [Probability with Martingales](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521406056) by David Williams. The book is very well written and fun to read.

A text that is easier, but IMO less fun is [A Probability Path](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081764055X) by Sidney Resnick. That book provides you with all the details and does everything in small steps.

A very concise book that contains the essentials is [Probability Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821828525) by S. R. S. Varadhan

Answer (score 11):

I suggest [A first look at rigorous probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812703713) by Jeffrey Rosenthal.

Comment: I second this response

Answer (score 5):

Although it is a rather thick book I recommend Billingsley's [Probability and Measure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471007102).

Answer (score 4):

Although it is little terse,  I like Durrett's [Probability: Theory and Examples](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest David Pollard's [A User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability](http://books.google.fr/books/about/A_User_s_Guide_to_Measure_Theoretic_Prob.html?id=B7Ch-c2G21MC&redir_esc=y), published in 2002.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Doob's *Measure Theory*. It does a nice job at blending probability with measure theory, perhaps close to the style you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about [www.probability.net](http://www.probability.net) for a nice introduction...